# Firebase Cloud Functions for Firestore are not triggering

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Cannot get Firebase Cloud Functions for Firestore to trigger on onWrite of my collection. Trying to setup device to device push notification for chat app. Function is deployed and on Pay as you go plan, however, changes in document, updates or create in "chats" collection is not triggering. Firebase cloud messaging is supposed to send a push and write to the log. Neither is happening. Push is working with other sources.

Thanks for your help, wish device to device push notifications was easier, plan is to watch the chat document and fire push notifications on update or create of new conversation. Open to other ideas. Thanks

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
  .document('chats/{chatID}')
  .onWrite((data, context) => {
    // Get an object representing the document
    console.log('chat triggered');
    // perform desired operations ...

    // See documentation on defining a message payload.
    var message = {
      notification: {
        title: 'Hello World!',
        body: 'Hello World!'
      },
      topic: context.params.chatID
    };

    // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    return admin.messaging().send(message)
      .then((response) => {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        return true
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
      });

  });
```

UPDATE: I'm using "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"

UPDATED: Updated the code to reflect what we currently have deployed, still not working.

Comment: Do you see an error message in the Functions log?

Comment: No errors in the functions log. Can’t get the method to trigger a log statement either

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "Can’t get the method to trigger a log statement either". In the Firebase console, in a browser (https://console.firebase.google.com/), if you select "Functions" in the vertical menu and select the "LOGS" tab, you will see the log from the Functions.

Comment: The log has no errors in it. Only thing in there is info statements with deploy times.

Comment: I'm not clear on the logs you're seeing.  Do you see a log indicating `sendNotification Function execution started`?

Comment: No, that is the problem

Comment: I'm using "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"

Comment: How are you writing the Firestore data at `chats/{chatID}`, code or the Firebase Console? If code, edit your post to include it.

Comment: console.log('chat triggered');

Comment: My question was about how you are writing to the Firestore database, not the log.  Whatever method you use, do you see the data change in the Firebase Console Database tab?

Comment: @BobSnyder we are not writing to the database at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170565/discussion-between-iosdevsf-and-bob-snyder).

Comment: You should review the [Cloud Function intro docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/?authuser=0): _Cloud Functions for Firebase lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests_.  You need provide a triggering event (Firestore write or another supported action) to cause your cloud function to execute.

Comment: @BobSnyder I'm not an idiot, I've been triggering events for days now and they aren't logging. Thus this post. Do you really think I would post here before checking the docs?

Comment: My comment was because I asked "how you are writing to the database" to trigger your Cloud Function and you responded "we are not writing to the database at all".

Comment: Having the same exact issue! I am writing to the db through the emulator. I wonder if the solution is any different when running from emulator.

Comment: did any one find solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are chances you are using the old syntax (before V1.0) with the new library (v1.0). See the Migration Guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff and check the version in your package.json file.

In addition, note that a Cloud Function must always return a Promise (or if you cannot, at least a value, for asynchronous functions). See this documentation (and associated video) which explain that in detail: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

You should modify you code this way:

If you are using Cloud Functions 1.0 or above:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
    .document('chats/{chatID}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
```

Returning:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
.document('chats/{chatID}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
  // Get an object representing the document
   console.log('chat triggered');
  // perform desired operations ...

    // See documentation on defining a message payload.
    var message = {
      notification: {
        title: 'Hello World!',
        body: 'Hello World!'
      },
      topic: context.params.chatID.   //<- If you are using a CF version under v1.0 don't change here
    };

    // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
    return admin.messaging().send(message).  //<- return the resulting Promise
      .then((response) => {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
        return true;    //<- return a value
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
        //return.  <- No need to return here
      });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `firebase-admin` [initialization syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?authuser=0#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase_admin), `admin.initializeApp()`, suggests you are using Cloud Functions SDK version 1.0.x.  The parameters for `onWrite()` [have changed in version 1.0.x](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff?authuser=0#event_parameter_split_into_data_and_context) from earlier versions.  You also need to [return a `Promise`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions?authuser=0) for asynchronous action `admin.messaging.send()`.  The three needed corrections are noted below:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
    .document('chats/{chatID}')
    .onWrite((data, context) => {  // <= CHANGE
      // Get an object representing the document
       console.log('chat triggered');
      // perform desired operations ...

        // See documentation on defining a message payload.
        var message = {
          notification: {
            title: 'Hello World!',
            body: 'Hello World!'
          },
          topic: context.params.chatID // <= CHANGE
        };

        // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
        return admin.messaging().send(message)  // <= CHANGE
          .then((response) => {
            // Response is a message ID string.
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
            return
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
            return
          });

});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me... I am running inside an emulator for both functions as well as firestore.

Comment: @Zorayr, it seems you are not using a token or topic when sending a message. That might be your issue. Either way, I'm sending message to a topic and my functions are not triggering anything on the function console.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was I was writing data that already existed in Firestore. The onWrite isn't triggered apparently if the data you're writing is exactly the same as what is there.